# Regex for differentiating between decimal and non-decimal values

Tags: c++, regex

I am having trouble with my regex.

```
regex nameInt("([A-Za-z]+)\\: ([0-9]+)");
regex nameDecimal("([a-zA-Z]+)\\: ([-+]?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)");
```

My input is as follows:

```
Jenny: 12
Mark: 12.6
```

But my input only ever flags the decimal, never the int.

Comment: Are you testing these against the whole multiline string or in individual lines? (with or without newline? With `regex_match` or `regex_search`?)

Comment: Needs a [mcve] not just a few snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try these expressions

Lines with int:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\: \d+$
```

Lines with decimal:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\: \d+\.\d+$
```

Comment: Could you explain how this differs from OP's regex and why it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    vector<string> v_s = {"Jenny: 12", "Mark: 12.6"};

    regex reg_int("^(.\\D+)\\: ([+-]?.\\d+)$");
    regex reg_double("^(.\\D+)\\: ([+-]?.\\d+\\.\\d+)$");

    for (const auto &s : v_s) {
        if (std::regex_match(s, reg_int))
            cout << "line with int value : " << s << endl;
        if (std::regex_match(s, reg_double))
            cout << "line with double value : " << s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
    line with int value : Jenny: 12
    line with double value : Mark: 12.6
```

with your regexes it is also works. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Do you know what `.\\D+` is matching? OP wants alphanumeric only.

Comment: \D means one character that is not a digit. I any case "([A-Za-z]+)\\: ([0-9]+)" works too,

Comment: And the dot before, what is it for?